# How to use AWS Lambda to check file in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Brand new to AWS Lambda so I'm not even sure if this is the right tool to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Basically what I'm trying to do is check if a file exists or if it was updated recently in S3.  If that file isn't there or wasn't updated recently I want an AMI to be cloned to an AWS instance.

1. Is the above possible?
2. Is Lambda the right tool for the job?

I'm fairly competent in JavaScript but have never used node.js or Python so writing a Lambda function seems complex to me.

Do you know of any resources that can help with building Lambda functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is possible and seems like a perfectly reasonable task to accomplish with AWS Lambda. Try looking at the examples AWS provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is will be easy if you've know about Javascript and know about NPM. Let me give you easy way with node js :

1. login to your AWS.
2. go to AWS console menu, the button at right top corner.
3. choose lambda, click function and create new function.
4. click **skip** button on blue print page.
5. **skip** configuration trigger page.
6. you will see configuration function page, then you can fill the function name, **runtime use NodeJS.4.3**, and choose code type **Edit Code Inline**
7. at the bottom from **Edit Code Inline** box, you must choose IAM Role that you ever have. if you don't have any IAM Roles, please go to AWS Console and choose **Identity and Access Management(IAM)**, select Roles and create it new.
8. If you have finish fill all field required, you can click next and create Lambda Function.

NOTE : in your Edit Code Inline Box, please write down this code :

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
     var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
     AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});
     var s3 = new AWS.S3();
     var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myFile.html'};
     s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {

     if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        // file does not exist, do something
     }
     else {
        console.log(data);
        //file exist, do something
     }    
  });
};
```

you can get **accessKeyId** from IAM menu -> Users -> Security Credentials -> Create Access Key. then you will get **secretAccessKey** too.

Hope this answer will be help you.

Comment: Thanks! Now i need to figure out how to get it to launch an AMI, but I'll try to figure that out for myself.